# Seeking Technical Solution to Restrict File Paths Exceeding 255 Characters on Windows Servers

Tags: windows, firefox, path, backuppc, zip

I've encountered a recurring issue with my Windows servers (both 2016 and 2019) crashing, and I've noticed that backups using BackupPC sometimes fail. Upon investigation, I discovered that the problem always stems from file paths exceeding 255 characters. Despite repeatedly advising my users to utilize shorter names and paths, they have not complied, leading to frustration as resolving this requires deleting the offending file and restarting the server, causing significant disruptions.

In search of a solution, I've explored alternative methods that allow users to bypass this limitation. For instance, when saving files through Firefox, the path characters are not counted, and certain third-party tools can extract files from deeply nested directories even with lengthy paths which makes the server crash.

I am seeking advice on implementing a technical restriction to prevent users from creating paths exceeding 255 characters. While educating users is the ideal approach, their reluctance necessitates a technical solution. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `educating users is the ideal approach` "educating" users isn't going to help for this. A far better option is to use a backup application that does not crash the system.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that every Windows environment has files that exceed the path limit, and I've never heard of it causing a server to crash. If BackupPC is causing the server to crash, because of this, or unrelated to this, I'd be looking for a new backup solution, preferably one that isn't homegrown.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Generell Aproach:

## The Registry way

- ### Please be aware that this could be harmful.

  - As it violates the Standards for Windows limitations.

using `Regedit` to edit

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
- and add/change `LongPathsEnabled` to Hexadezimal 1

Lazy Admins using Powershell:
*

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" ` 
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

Using this, after a restart, it will enable Windows 10, 1607+ to use extended pathes at all.
Thats meaned as a Workaround for your issue imho.

## Native Dos

- There is also in case of you need to delete an extend path a other solution

  - `subst`

```
subst /?
Assigns a drive letter to a path.

SUBST [Drive1: [Drive2:]Path]
SUBST Drive1: /D

Drive1: Drive letter to assign to the path.
[Drive2:]Path Physical drive and physical path to assign to the
virtual drive.
/D Deletes the association for (virtual) Drive1.

SUBST without parameters displays the virtual drives created with SUBST.
```

That means you can reduce the path by around at least 250 characters, which, based on my knowledge of the past two decades and beyond, is almost sufficient.

## Notice to BackupPC

### BackupPC has its last release 2020

Consider to change to a well known business Product like Veeam.
Veeam has a Community edition free of charge.

References:
[HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)
[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)
[BackupPC](https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/)

Comment: 1. No, it's not, as even with that, when people will save files and want to access them later using explorer it won't work
2. It's not possible, I already did that but users are always doing new folder inside new folder etc...
3. I don't want to change, everybody is used to it and it's free for entreprise use

Comment: This is a setting for the client that the GPO needs to send to the client. The client must have Windows 10 1607 or newer. Older clients have a fixed number of characters imho. NTFS does usually support upto 32k Characters

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize Group Policy to enforce path length limitations. By configuring the "Enable Win32 long paths" policy under `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem`, you can enforce a maximum path length of 255 characters. Additionally, implementing file system auditing can help track and identify violations of path length restrictions:

1. `Security Settings > Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > Object Access`
2. `Audit File System >> Succes and Failure`