# Can't fix error: "The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder"

Tags: windows, filesystems

I'm trying to enable long paths on Windows Server 2019, but can't make it work. I've tried both the usual solutions:

1. Using GPEDIT and enabling long paths at Local Computer Policy >
   Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System >
   Filesystem
2. Enable the LongPathsEnabled regkey
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

Even with these, I still can't create a folder/file path longer than ~260 characters. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeking Technical Solution to Restrict File Paths Exceeding 255 Characters on Windows Servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/1153621/seeking-technical-solution-to-restrict-file-paths-exceeding-255-characters-on-wi)

Comment: it is similar to your request. in your case it may require to use subst

Answer (score 0):

**long file paths** are not compatible with all programs, that's why it's not recommended to activate **long file paths**. Even Excel & Co have problems to open files which are stored that way. I really recommend not to use this feature, unless you can 100% make sure that all your software supports it. I recommend to teach/educate your users that file paths have a maximum size and that they cannot create endless subfolders/filenames. If your users really want to stay with their current way to go, use a database instead of the plain filesystem, for example **Nextcloud**.

PS you can test if your software supports **long file paths** if you can use a [UNC path (Universal Naming Convention)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention) to open a file with that software